# Why is this SDL program not loading my image?

Tags: c++, sdl, unresolved-external, sdl-image

I was recently trying to understand how to load an image in SDL. However, when I followed a guide on how to do this, the code wasn't working for some reason. Instead, I get an unresolved external symbol error:

```
unresolved external symbol IMG_LoadPNG_RW referenced in function "void __cdecl windowcr(void)" (?windowcr@@YAXXZ)
```

Code:

**windowcreate.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef WINDOWCREATE_H

#define WINDOWCREATE_H

#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void windowcr() {

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDLwindow", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 46, 139, 87, 255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Surface* image = IMG_LoadPNG_RW(SDL_RWFromFile("worldmap.png", "rb"));
    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image);

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;

    while (running) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
            }
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x0D) & 0x8000) {
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
            break;
        }
    }

}

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "windowcreate.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    windowcr();

    return 0;

}
```

I have tried to look up ways to fix this, I moved the image to the same directory as the project itself, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Your linking error has nothing to do with the location of the png file. The png file is only needed when your code actually executes. In that case it needs to be in the current working directory when your application executes. However also in this case you have no application because the linker failed to find the  the `IMG_LoadPNG_RW` symbol in the libraries and object files that you provided. I expect you are not linking to the SDL_image library.

Comment: How are you compiling this code? Are you linking with the required libraries for that function?

Comment: It seems you are not linking with the library containing the symbol `IMG_LoadPNG_RW`. However you did not provide any information about how you linked this program, so this is only a guess.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you, the lib and dll files of SDL_image were not properly linked.